# How can I show a circle around touches on an iOS device?

Tags: iphone, ios, location, touch, point

I have a presentation where I'd like to demo my application. I'm using AirServer to mirror my iPod to my mac which I will connect to the projector.

Android has an developer option of showing a circle when you touch the screen so the audience can see where the presenter is touching the screen. Is there a way to do the same on an iPod touch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be the best solution but you could create an image that you fade in that would put a semi-opaque covering over the screen with the exception of your desired touch/focal point.

Setting touchedEnabled to NO on the image would still allow you or a user to click the button, at which point you could check if the image is shown, if it is, fade it back out and continue your presentation

*If this is a feature you wanted to keep in your app i'd suggest setting an NSUserDefault value to mark a value that it has or has not been shown.  Once a user sees the guided access, set that value to true and don't show again.